# Word for a person who is challenged to a bet

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I want to challenge my friend to do something (like a bet), what would you call such a person? Challenged person? Challengee?

For example:

> I challenge my friend to kiss a girl and he'll receive 4 pints. I'm
>   the challenger, he's the [...]

Comment: You could say **"challengee"** or **"challenged"**, but "challengee" sounds odd and "challenged" sounds like you're describing a **characteristic**, eg that he's "mentally challenged" or something similar.  In duelling, the two parties would be called "The challenger" and "The challenged".

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Is there no synonym or other creative way of describing the two parties?

Comment: If there is then someone will probably post it...

Comment: 'I'm the challenger, he's the person who is definitely going to get the meaningful agreement of whatever girl he kisses and not be a complete pillock about the whole weird bet.'?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/challengee

Answer (score 1):

This is either the exact word you're looking for or I'm very close to finding it:

> [**stakeholder**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stakeholder) (n.)
>   1. (In gambling) an independent party with whom each of those who make a wager deposits the money or counters wagered.

This definition doesn't fit your situation *exactly*, but you can see how it applies well. The stakes (4 pints) are held by him and his actions.

After a little more digging I came across another term that made me feel slightly disappointed in myself for not knowing it already:

> [**taker**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/taker) (n.)
>   2. A person who takes a bet or accepts an offer or challenge

Comment: I think ‘Stakeholder’ would be, as the definition says, a separate person who holds the 4 pints for the period between the challenge being accepted and completed. The point being that the challenger cannot renege on the bet and the taker can’t just sink the pints and never kiss the girl. If your answer was just Taker, I would upvote.

Comment: @Spagirl I agree. That's why I noted that it doesn't quite fit.

Answer (score 0):

One word that might work is "contender", which means a person who is trying to win something in a contest or competition. It seems to make most sense when describing someone who was challenged, not the other way around. In your example, you would be the challenger and he would be the contender.

Comment: In this case I'm not really talking about a competition... it's a bet, but friendly... contender seems like a nice word, but it seems a bit to "sportslike" ?

Comment: I apologize for being, what, several weeks late in writing this comment? Maybe the word you're looking for is "rival"—not quite enemies but fierce competitors.

Answer (score 0):

He is the COUNTERPART;may be an adversary, an opponent or antagonist or,even, an enemy. He is simply the counterpart, the person challenged.

The word is so commonplace that I thought it unnecessary to explain. Still, the word is from a French word, Countre part meaning duplicate of a legal document and, it still carries that unsavory connotations of a bill book — mere copy. But today it is more likely to describe people.

Vocabulary.com very adeptly goes on to elaborate:" Counterparts aren't duplicates, of course, but they have similar skills and responsibilities. If you play soccer, your counterpart is the player on the other team who plays the same position." For example:

- I like my counterpart to down vote only if it is not for nothing.

Comment: Hello, Barid. You need to explain with reference and research why you think those words could answer the question. Your question was flagged as low-quality for its length and content. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **the one challenged**, which emphasises the binary relation with the challenger. It has some good results in Google books, [among which](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HFyeYZfD410C&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22the+one+challenged%22&source=bl&ots=SrebJysAKj&sig=b_6730U1ghn3z8_W7V7pjErr4Tc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20one%20challenged%22&f=false) :

> The public scrutinizes the reaction of the one challenged.

(Paul in the Greco-Roman World: A Handbook edited by J. Paul Sampley)

Answer (score -2):

employer - employee.
challenger - challengee.
Employee has two e's because of its French etymology.  Challenger doesn't have the same etymology, so there doesn't seem to be any reason for the two e's. 
If you just want a word with the same meaning, then contestant might work.   That fits with the etymology of the word challenger. If you think of your challenge as an experiment then subject will work.